# How do I animate the texture mapping location in the node editor?

Tags: animation, texturing, node-editor

I have linked a magic texture to the base color of my principled bsdf in the shading node editor. In the menu on the right under item, there is a section for texture mapping. When I change the location, the texture moves on my object. I want to animate this movement. If I try to insert a keyframe to the slider for location x, it says failed to resolve path to property. Try manually specifying this using a keying set instead. I have no idea what that means. How do I get the location for a texture node to animate?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't animate *this* texture mapping. (Or maybe you can with Python scripting ?)

What you have to do is add a *Texture Coordinate* and a *Mapping* node before your *Magic Texture* node. You can then animate the fields from the *Mapping* node.

[image]

Comment: Dude, I was messing with both texture coordinates and mapping and couldn’t figure it out, thank you so much. Just want to say how cool it is to have this website with people like you who are willing to help out random people on the internet, it’s great. Blender has so much to do but it’s difficult to navigate and not easy to find answers to specific things with google, so thank you for doing what you do and shout-out to blender.stackexchange this place is a huge help

Comment: I'm glad it helped ! Don't hesitate to come here for questions, as long as you add any relevant detail and take the time to from it correctly, you will get relevant answers :). Also if you're searching for similar problems, don't use the search function on site site, use google and add `site:stackexchange.com` at the end. Very soon you'll be able to help others too :)